# Breezejs/knockout - how do you combine entities?

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I am very new to breeze.js and I need to be able to combine two entities.

Right now I cannot get all of the information I need in one query.  My solution is to get both entities separately and then combine in code.

Here are the two queries:

```
         var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("EmployeeLaborTasks")
        .where("task_ID", "==", taskID)
        .orderBy("employee_ID")
        .expand(["Employee", "LaborCategory"]);


         var query = breeze.EntityQuery
        .from("ForecastedHours")
        .where("task_ID", "==", taskID)
        .expand("Employee");
```

EmployeeLaborTasks is a join table with foreign keys for the taskID, employeeID and LaborCategoryID.  This allows me to load the Employees and their LaborCategories based on the taskID.

However, I still need each employee's forecastedHours. . .

ForecastedHours are entered by month, so an employee could have many entries over the year (12 max). Because of this, there is no applicable navigation property that I can use to add ForecastedHours to the first query. This table contains a foreign key for taskID and employeeID.  Thus, a 2nd one is necessary.

I would like to join these two resulting entities on employee.ID.  Ultimately, I will use this information in a grid (via knockout/Durandal), displaying the employee name, labor category, and forecast hours over 12 months.

Is this possible?  Will joining these entities ruin any Breeze.js tracking that makes the info updateable?

I am also wondering if it would be better to combine them via knockout's ko.computed but I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

In response to Dominictus below, I am posting the data models for the tables in question:

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyEmployeeID { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
    public decimal UtilizationTarget { get; set; }
    public virtual Office OfficeLocation { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public virtual JobGrade JobGrade { get; set; } 
}



public class EmployeeLaborTasks
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int Employee_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Task")]
    public int Task_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual LaborCategory LaborCategory { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LaborCategory")]
    public int LaborCategory_ID { get; set; }
}


public class ForecastedHours
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public virtual Task Task { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Task")]
    public int Task_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int Employee_ID { get; set; }
}


public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Contract")]
    public int ContractID { get; set; }

    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }

    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}


public class LaborCategory
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Rate { get; set; }
    public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
    [Timestamp]
    public Byte[] LastModified { get; set; }
    public virtual User ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Breeze is a bit more powerful than this and can do it the way you want.

In BreezeController make:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<EmployeeLaborTasks> NameHere(){
    return _contextProvider.Context.EmployeeLaborTasks.Include("Employee").Include("LaborCategory").Include("Employee.ForecastedHours");
}
```

I will assume Employee has

```
public virtual <ForecastedHour> ForecastedHours {get;set;}
```

and also that EmployeeLaborTasks (this is just for employee, it should be defined for all other connections) has

```
public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
[ForeignKey("EmployeeId")]
public Employee Employee {get;set;}
```

After that you can write only one query on client:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery
    .from("NameHere")
    .where("task_ID", "==", taskID)
    .orderBy("employee_ID")
```

You put all that into one observable variable. To place it into grid, you would do something like this (pseudo-code here):

```
foreach employeeLaborTasks as singleTask{
   display (singleTask.employee.name)
   display (singleTask.laborCategory.name)
   foreach (singleTask.employee.forecastedHours as singleForecast){
      display (singleForecast.name)
   }
   display (newline)
}
```

Comment: Hey Dominictus, thanks so much for your reply and your generous help.  I am still not getting the forecasted hours (although everything else comes through with mods to the BreezeController).  Unfortunately, I did not have the line: 'public virtual <ForecastedHour> ForecastedHours {get;set;}' in my Employee.  I tried adding it, but the formatting did not seem to work and so I tried variations, such as 'public virtual ForecastedHours Hours {get;set;}'.  I will post my data model for the tables above.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Try dropping foreign key on Task in ForecastHours and then Employee should be able to have ForecastHours. You should really try to draw your model on paper and see dependencies, the way I see it, something smells fishy and needs redesign ;) I believe ForecastHour doesn't need direct connection to Task, otherwise, you can connect them by querying for EmployeeLaborTasks (altough not ideal)

Comment: I dropped the foreign key for Task in ForecastedHours but there is still a problem.  It's as if there needs to be a foreign key in Employee itself that references ForecastedHours.  But that seems backwards because there will be many hour entries to one employee.  I've also tried to fix up the dependencies in the tables, but I'm still not having any luck.

Comment: Got it!  Just needed to use a list: public virtual List<ForecastedHours> ForecastedHours { get; set; }.  Marking this as accepted answer.  Thanks so much Dominictus!